# The usage of 一覧

Tags: word-choice, meaning

Let me describe the scenario first. The lever of the following faucet can only be turned 180 degrees until the tip of the lever touches the base.
However, because the lever can be detached, I can turn the valve up to 900 degrees (= 5 x 180 degrees).

[image]

Today my coworker borrowed a hose that I also wanted to use. He had to fill several buckets. Because I did want to wait too long for him to fill all of the buckets, I turned the valve 900 degrees such that the water flowed faster, which in turn reducing the time taken to fill of all the buckets.

Once I turned the valve, I leaved it and resumed my own job. Several minutes later, he called me and said something like this:

> 一覧止めらないから、決してそれをするな！

Note that my listening comprehension is not good enough.

I looked up the dictionary, [一覧](http://tangorin.com/general/ichiran) means "at a glance". So does the sentence above means "I cannot close the valve quickly, don't turn the valve 900 degrees!"?

## Question

Generally, how to use the word 一覧?

Comment: 「 **一度に**止められないから」って言ったのかな…？　（`止めらない` 「止**ま**らない」か「止めら**れ**ない」だと思うのですがどっちでしょうね)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

一覧 usually means a (full) list, a catalog.

> - 日本語の助詞の一覧
>     (full) list of Japanese particles
> - 質問一覧 (link)
>     (all) questions

一覧する exists as a verb, and it means "to take a brief look (from start to end)", "to give a glance," or sometimes "to have a full view." But it's uncommon and literary, and you will hardly hear this in everyday conversations. 一覧して can mean "at a glance," but 一覧 on its own do not work as an adverb.

> - 書類を一覧した。 (uncommon)
>     I briefly went over the document.
> - 一覧してそれが彼だと解った。 (literary and rare)
>     I noticed it was him at a glance.
> - この山からは東京が一覧できます。
>     From this mountain you can have a full view of Tokyo.

In conversations people usually say 一目見て, 見た瞬間に or 見てすぐに instead of 一覧して.

So... you must have misheard something. I'm pretty certain that your coworker did **not** say 一覧, although I have no idea what he actually said. One similar-sounding word is [一旦](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E4%B8%80%E6%97%A6&ref=sa) (="once"). 一旦止められない doesn't make sense, but you can say something like this:

> - 一旦開けたら止められない。
>     Once you open it, you can't stop it.

Comment: It was probably 1ターン.